# Null reference exception-control

Tags: reference, null, controls

I get some kind of errors and can't understand why!

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] 
header.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +867 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92 
IRIPL.Sys5B.Web.cWebPageComponent.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +39 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: You should properly format your code for people to read it easier and .. you have not asked a question.. what is your question?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is impossible for us to help you find the bug. Please show us the code where this occurs, the relevant part of your `Page_Load` function. Try to make it a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit it into your post. Good luck!